# Saving user input in VB

Tags: vb.net, text, input

At the start of my VB application I am asking user to type his email and password into two text boxes. If login will be successful, I would like to save entered email and password as a Login.txt file into relative directory. I would like to overwrite all old info in the file.

I would like that every time the application starts; it will read this Login.txt file and displays email and password back in same two text boxes, so user do not need to type it every time he is doing Login.

What is the right code for this?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do not save a password in plain text.  Instead, save a revocable token from your server, like OAuth 2.

Comment: If you're saving all the login information for use as default next time, why bother having a login at all? You should at least require that your user enter his password.

Comment: Go to Project -> Properties -> settings.  Then it is just `My.Settings.Save` if you dont have it set to automatically save.

Comment: Security level 0 - no password, Security level 0.1 - password saved in file. You have to decide what is security for your application. Sound that you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to follow @Plutonix comment steps,
you can create two new settings as string type and select "user" scope (not application), and also ensure to keep empty the default values.

So in your code to save the values everytime when you want you can do this:

```
My.Settings.Email = EmailTextBox.text
My.Settings.Pass  = PassTextBox.text
```

And to load the values:

```
EmailTextBox.text = My.Settings.Email 
PassTextBox.text  = My.Settings.Pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this method for along time and i think it would help you. 
When you open up VB double click in the soloution explorer "My Project"
It will come up with tabs along the side of the window you need to click the settings tab. It will come up with a table and one of the rows will have the name "settings" in it. In your case you want to name it "email" then press enter. Another row will appear again change the name from "settings" to "Password" then press enter. When you have done this part this is the coding part:

CODING:

Textbox1.text = my.settings.email

Textbox2.text = my.settings.password

My.settings.save

Ok so that is the coding out of the way

All you need to do now is insert the coding from above into the coding of the button you want to click to remember the details.
Then after you have done that step click debug or the play button or the (f5) key.

Hope this works for you i will edit it if it doesn't

thanks

Answer (score 0):

hope that the following reference will give solution for your problem

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pth = "d:\user_login"
        If Directory.Exists(pth) = False Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pth) 'create a folder in the path is no such folder is existing
        End If
    End Sub
```

this will create a directory in your D: drive at first run

```
Private Sub login_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles login.Click
        ' works like session veriables 
        uname = username.Text ' store user name to a public verible for future reference till the application restarted
        pwd = pasword.Text    ' store password to a public verible for future reference till the application restarted
        'save user name and password as small text file for future reference
        'Dim rtc As New RichTextBox
        rtc.Clear() ' clear the rtc content
        rtc.Text = "Username :" & username.Text & Chr(13) & "Password :" & pasword.Text 'create a text document and write values on it
        rtc.SaveFile(pth & "\" & Now.Month.ToString & Now.Day & "_" & Now.Hour.ToString & "_" & Now.Minute.ToString & ".txt") 'save the document in the above path with current date and time as name
    End Sub
```